# Cannot install Black update on Lumia 520

Tags: lumia, lumia-black-update, lumia-520

I have a Lumia 520. Despite using wifi, I am not able to get the Lumia Black update, it is stuck at 0%.

What should I do? I have made sure I have enough free space on my phone.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is "stuck at 0%". Downloading the update? Installing it? What exactly does your screen show? And how long has it been stuck like that?

Comment: Even am suffering with same problem, it stuck at 0% downloading the update, I am using cellular data please help

Comment: The update download can be done over wifi only @Rohit. Please use wifi only during download.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your on WiFi, secondly you have to make sure that you are not on Battery Saver. If you are on battery saver the download process doesn't start.